# How to serialize an exception in a library class Project?

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, dynamics-crm, libphonenumber

I want to use PhoneNumbers library  from Google, in my CRM Dynamics Plugin.

My plugin try to parse a phone number.
When executing, I got the execption below:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'PhoneNumbers.NumberParseException,aug.R2BCore.Crm.Plugins

the exception class was missing the Serialized attribute, I added it.

Here is the code of the exception class:

```
namespace PhoneNumbers
{
    public enum ErrorType
    {
        INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE,
        // This generally indicates the string passed in had less than 3 digits in it. More
        // specifically, the number failed to match the regular expression VALID_PHONE_NUMBER in
        // PhoneNumberUtil.java.
        NOT_A_NUMBER,
        // This indicates the string started with an international dialing prefix, but after this was
        // stripped from the number, had less digits than any valid phone number (including country
        // code) could have.
        TOO_SHORT_AFTER_IDD,
        // This indicates the string, after any country code has been stripped, had less digits than any
        // valid phone number could have.
        TOO_SHORT_NSN,
        // This indicates the string had more digits than any valid phone number could have.
        TOO_LONG
    }

    [Serializable] // added 
    public class NumberParseException : Exception
    {
        public readonly ErrorType ErrorType;

        public NumberParseException(ErrorType errorType, string message) :
            base(message)
        {
            ErrorType = errorType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should reference the assembly `System.Runtime.Serialization` and use `using System;`.

Comment: the project was targeting 3 frameworks: net3, net2, net45, I cleaned these target, I let only net45 and it is working, it is now recognize [SERIALIZED], Now it throws a new error: >System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'PhoneNumbers.NumberParseException,aug.R2BCore.Crm.Plugins

Comment: Allright, please delete the question then to save time of people trying to help.

Comment: I changed the content of the question, to match with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin runs in a separate application domain context. When you throw exception, this is then propagated to SandboxExecutionWorkerProcess that is executing in different application domain then your plugin is and don't know about your custom exeption type. So regardless how you serialize the exception the type has to be de-serializable on the other side.

I'd recomment following approach (exception wrapping):

```
public abstract class BasePlugin : IPlugin {
  protected abstract DoExecute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);
  public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    try { 
      this.DoExecute(serviceProvider); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

If you have fixed set of custom exception types, you can enhance this code to handle just those. Also beware that doing this you're exposing stack trace to CRM users - fine if you're developing plugin just for your company, but if you're ISV you should consider hiding it.